# How do I automate the update of SNAPSHOT dependencies to the latest released versions when using maven

Tags: maven, process, release-management, configuration-management

I am trying to define a release process for our project.

I was able to use the maven release plugin to accomplish the release but I had to manually update all of our internal SNAPSHOT dependencies to release versions prior to the prepare and then again back to SNAPSHOT versions after the release.

I have used the maven versions plugin and it detects my corporate dependencies that are SNAPSHOT builds and lists the correct release build to use.

I tried the maven release plugin, prepare goal, and complains about the SNAPSHOT versions in my dependencies.

Is there a way to do a release that updates the SNAPSHOT depenedencies to latest released versions and then back to SNAPSHOT versions after the release? Or maybe this is just not the way you are supposed to be using maven with releases and SNAPSHOTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a realease with maven: it must be definitive. i.e. once it is created it cannot change anymore (i.e. the sources cannot change **and the dependencies** cannot change).

So when you create a release of moduleA and moduleA having a dependency on moduleB. moduleB must be released before moduleA is released, and moduleA MUST depends on a released version of moduleB.

One important thing is that you shouldn't *go back to SNAPSHOT* version. At least as I understand it means :

- create moduleB-1.0.0 release
- changing dependency to moduleB-1.0.0
- create moduleA-1.0.0 release
- then change the dependency back to moduleB-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

It must be clear that once moduleB-1.0.0 exists (i.e. is released): the artifact moduleB-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT shouldn't be used anymore.

Instead of *go back to SNAPSHOT* should *update dependency to next SNAPSHOT version* (for instance moduleB-SNAPSHOT-1.0.1)

That being said, releasing a module depending on many SNAPSHOT artifacts is not an easy process, since every dependency must be released prior to releasing your main artifact.

What we have, most of the time, is a main artifact depending on many other artifacts (let's call them the corporate-modules) having the same versionning strategy. And so you can define a property `corporate-module-version` holding the version used by many dependencies in one place.

The release process is the following:

- release every snapshot dependency with version number 1.0.0 (using the maven-release-plugin: after this step all pom.xml of your corporate-module in SCM are 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT) (see important remark at the end of this post to facilitate this step)
- **manually** changing the `corporate-module-version` property to "1.0.0" in the main artifact (so that all SNAPSHOT dependencies are replaced by just released versions)
- commit the modified pom.xml holding the `corporate-module-version`
- with maven-release-plugin: releasing the main artifact (and after that, the new version in the SCM will be something like 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
- **manually** changing the `corporate-module-version` property to "1.0.1-SNAPSHOT" in the main artifact (so that all dependencies are replaced by latest snapshot versions)

**Important remark**: having a multi-module parent project holding all your corporate modules is a must to perform at once the release of of all corporate modules. To not having too much trouble with the maven-release-plugin and the multi-module parent project be sure to put your parent pom.xml one directory upper all your child pom.xml (it's the designed recommend by maven, but unfortunately, sometimes, eclipse users don't follow it because eclipse don't like hierarchical projects)

Comment: When I said go back to the SNAPSHOT I did mean the next version of the snapshot.  It looks like I will have to manually change the versions of corporate depends for each release, not an ideal solution but doable since all the versions are defined in the top level pom as a property.